# Receiving undefined while consoling the zero index value

Tags: angular, undefined, ngfor

I try to get the zero index of the array, but I am getting undefined value and I can't bind the value in html using ngFor:

```
categories: Category[] = [];


  getSubItems(): void {
    this.http
      .get<Category[]>('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php')
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.categories = data;
        console.log(this.categories[0]);
      });
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="food-item" *ngFor="let art of categories">
    <img class="card-img-top" style="max-width:300px;" role="button">
    <h1>{{art.strCategory}}</h1>
</div>
```

Here I am trying to console log the zero index of that array but I'm getting undefined. However, when I console log `this.categories` I am getting the data.

Comment: Are you sure the "data" you receive are not null or undefined?

Comment: No its not null or undefined as I said I am able to console the this.categories but not not able to find the zeroth index, whereas when I try to bind the data using *ngFor Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed getting this error

Comment: are you sure it is an array? Can you show us what you receive in "data"?

Comment: What I think is that your "data" returns an object, not an array

Comment: Yeah is there any way that I can handle that ?

Comment: I need to know how your "data" is formed

Comment: {categories: Array(14)}
categories
: 
(14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: Does that help to find the problem, what I recieved in the console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your problem is fixed doing this:

```
getSubItems(): void {
 this.http
  .get<{categories: Category[]}>('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php')
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.categories = data?.categories;
    console.log(this.categories[0]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Property 'categories' does not exist on type 'Category[]' I'm getting this error

Comment: just update the answer. I suggest you to read some typescript documentation

Comment: Yeah Thanks man it worked now, yeah I'm totally new to typescript, will read more documents though

Comment: can you please add the link in the comment to look for the concept which I got struck right now ?

Comment: I accepted the answer but for some reason I can't upvote this its saying it need some 15 reputations to upvote

Comment: I really like official documentation so I suggest you https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html
and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object